# Unable to do tcpreplay of edited wireshark file

Tags: wireshark, tcpreplay, editcap

what I did -

1. Got a wireshark capture of web traffic.
2. Edited the capture file to remove one GET request. (removed that line using editcap)
3. Saved the edited file (from step 2)
4. Did a tcpreplay of this file.

When I do this, I get an error: Fatal Error: Error opening pcap file: bad dump file format.

Any inputs on what could be wrong? Am I doing something wrong in the way I have edited my wireshark pcap file?

thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

The default editcap capture file output type is pcapng.

A quick look at the tcpreplay docs shows mentions only of libpcap format (and not pcapng).

So: Maybe the solution is to specify the '-F pcap' option to editcap to specify the capture file output format as libpcap format.

Update:

From the tcpreplay FAQ:

"Does Tcpreplay support Pcap-Ng/NTAR files?

Yes. The Tcpreplay suite uses ​libpcap for reading & writing pcap files. If you have libpcap 1.1.0 or higher, then tcpreplay, tcprewrite, etc can read pcap-ng files. If you have an older version of libpcap, you should upgrade to the latest version as earlier versions of libpcap have bugs with pcap-ng files. "

So: (assuming that you're using a version of libpcap >= 1.1.0) I'm not sure what the problem is. You might still want to try specifying pcap output format to see if that makes a difference.

Also: Are you able to read the original capture file (before editing) with tcpreplay ?  (What is the format of the original file ? (Use 'capinfos filename' to determine the file type).